# Upload image to server more faster in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, image-upload

In my iPhone app am doing image upload to server using ASIHTTPRequest. But its taking more than 20 seconds to upload. Is there any better way to upload images to server.? Please help!!!

Comment: You need to provide more information... how big is the image, how long does it take, what type of network, how long do you expect it to take?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and set a low quality compression value in order to reduce the size of the image. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) you can find more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could compress the image data and upload if that reduces the size of the image and is a feasible thing to do. You are aware that the upload speed as well as definition of 'better way' are dependent on your 1. connectivity bandwidth, 2. Size of image. 3. Expected upload time. You could look into other frameworks such as [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) if they give you better performance.